# Equations didn't fit

Tags: beamer, math-mode, equations, amsmath

I created a presentation with University of Hamburg beamer theme, which can be found [here](https://github.com/satta/zbh-beamer-theme). However, in a slide, I wrote long equations but they did not fit and I cannot fix this problem. This is the print screen of this slide. 
[image]

Comment: Use the ``split`` environment of the ``amsmath`` package to split the equations and use two lines for each.

Comment: That's not possible. It does not look good and also, I have to put all these three equations in one slide.

Comment: Or since splitting the equations will make multiple lines so  you will go off the bottom of the screen you could use \small but perhaps there is too much information on one slide and you should split but then use two slides.

Comment: I think you are falling into the trap of putting far too much on one slide: Till's advice in the `beamer` manual on structuring a talk is very good, and he warns against using too many equations!

Comment: Additionally, eq numbering on a presentation is an instant distractor and tells the audience a bit of your attitude. They have no way to scroll back in your presentation so eq. numbering is redundant. If necessary they will point out the slide using the slide number. (Unless you distribute them as lecture notes which is still not a good idea)

Comment: Looking at your equations, they are **very** similar to one another except for changes of variables. You should be able to use that to simplify how you present your results in your presentation, if not on the slides. And given how **many** variables you use, might it not be better to use more indices, to use fewer distinct symbols and make it easier for your audience to figure out the pattern (or for you to hint at it instead of writing it out in full, three times)?

Comment: yes of course they are almost the same, if I don't count the changes in the variables. But I need to show them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you really need to do this, then there is the `shrink` option to the `frame` environment in `beamer`.  One writes `\begin{frame}[shrink=20]` to get at least a 20% reduction in size.
So a minimal version of your example looks like:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[shrink=20]
\frametitle{Vector Error Correction Models}
\begin{equation}
  \Delta X_t = \alpha_0 + \sum_{i=1}^I a_i \Delta X_{t-i} +
  \sum_{j=1}^J b_j \Delta Y_{t-j} + \sum_{k=1}^K c_k \Delta Z_{t-k}
  + \Theta \mu_{t-1} + \epsilon_t
\end{equation}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

producing

[image: Squeezed output]

whereas without `shrink` one gets:

[image: Original output]

Note the `shrink` option implies the `squeeze` option, which removes alot of the vertical spacing.  See the beamer userguide for more information.